# Starting an Ember.js Project

Tags: javascript, ember.js, npm, yeoman

I'm new to Ember.js and I'm use to just typing in `rails project33`. But, when I want to start a new Ember project I'm going:

1. `mkdir project43 && cd project43`
2. `npm install -g generator-ember`
3. `yo ember`

This brings up all the boilerplate code in my folder which is fine, but is there not a more simple way to jumping into creating a new application? And does Ember REALLY need all this boiler code? It seems...excessive.

Comment: You can checkout http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/ . After installing you can create a new app with `ember new appname`. Hope it helps

Comment: No, it does not need that much. You can install ember on a static HTML file and put all your app code there if you want. It totally depends on how dynamic you need your project to be and what sort of storage solutions are required, if any.

Answer (score 2):

You are starting a new project and you are using Yeoman so what you are doing is specific to the tool that you are using. So with Yeoman you have to make a directory then cd into it and run `yo ember`. Having to do `npm install -g generator-ember` (which you do once to install node package globally) is to install the generators for ember that Yeoman needs for you to run commands like `yo ember` from the command line for use with Yeoman with Ember.

Now if you were to use a tool called ember-cli http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/ creating a new project would be a little different you have two options. One is just running `ember new <appname>` from the command line that will create a new folder with whatever name you used for the 'appname'. The second way with ember-cli is similar to Yeoman where you would make a new directory, cd into that directory and run `ember init`from the command line.

Both Yeoman and ember-cli install files and setup a folder structure for you. I believe these files and folders are what you are calling boilerplate. When you look into your rails project you will see alot of boilerplate if you will but its there for a reason. All of this boilerplate is helping you and assisting you in not having to setup things like a build solution, installing dependencies, testing solutions, css compilation etc. Ember-cli and Yeoman are built differently under the hood and implement different things but essentially set out to solve the same thing, tooling for building client-side apps.

If you just making a quick app you can do something similar to http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/ however once you app starts to grow having a clear separation of files and a application structure will be of benefit.

Hope this helps, hope you have fun learning ember.